# Java - accessing private fields of enum from overridden methods

Tags: java, enums

I was playing around with enums and I saw that this code won't compile:

```
class TrafficLight{
    enum Color{
        RED(23){
            private int y=5;
            @Override
            public int sum(){
                return val+y;
            }
        }, 
        GREEN(24);
        private int val;
        Color(int x){
            val=x;
        }
        public int sum(){
            return val;
        }
    }
}
```

The error is: `non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context`

However, if I change the access modifier on `val` to protected the code compiles without problems.

I am trying to understand why exactly does that happen. I was told that I can think about enums to be a static class with anonymous subclasses (one subclass for each discrete value).

I guess it can kind of fit because if the field is protected it can be accessed from within `RED`, but because `RED` doesn't have a constructor of his own, his own `val` will not be initialized, so if `val` is private it doesn't have anything to access.

I wanted to hear if that is a correct way to think about enums, and if my explanation makes sense.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think of enums as immutable value classes, where the values represent all possible instances. I didn't even know it was possible to subclass an enumeration.

Comment: Thank you, but I would like an explanation that involves inheritance as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, Enum class is a special class but it still compliance with Java scope.

In Java, child class cannot access any private methods, variables from parent class.

For above question, enum `Red` is extending Color class (and only values inside enum can sort of extending it). In order to access the value of `val` from `Color`, you can change the scope from

```java
private int val;
```

to

```java
int val;
```